# Set the value of an object in a complex plist file

Tags: plist

I want to change the value of an object in a Dictionary, however, the Dictionary structure is complex. That is;

```
<dict>
<key>Content</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Description</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Duration</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Image</key>
        <string></string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Description</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Duration</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Image</key>
        <string></string>
    </dict>
</array>
</dict>
```

I can access an element with (Where the plist file is called Data)

```
[Data objectForKey:[[[Data objectForKey:@"Content"]objectAtIndex:selectedIndex]objectForKey:@"Description"]]
```

How do I set the value at for this object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
[[[Data objectForKey:@"Content"] objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] setObject:@"foo" forKey:@"Description"];
```

It set the string `foo` for the key `Description` into array at index `selectedIndex` into the dictionary with key `Contents`.